# How to check if string contains any specified words then pass an error out of the function

Tags: php, function

I've been using the below code fine for a quick and efficient function of adding BB codes in my site.

```
function replace($text) {
//User Emotions
$text = str_replace(":)", "<img src=\"smiles/cool.gif\">", $text);

//User formatting
$text = str_replace("[center]", "<center>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[/center]", "</center>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[colour=red]", "<font color = red>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[/colour]", "</font>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[colour=blue]", "<font color = blue>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[/colour]", "</font>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[colour=green]", "<font color = green>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[/colour]", "</font>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[colour=orange]", "<font color = orange>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[/colour]", "</font>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[colour=white]", "<font color = white>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[/colour]", "</font>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[colour=black]", "<font color = black>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[/colour]", "</font>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[colour=code]", "<font color = code>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[/colour]", "</font>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[b]", "<strong>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[/b]", "</strong>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[i]", "<i>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[/i]", "</i>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[u]", "<u>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[/u]", "</u>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[move]", "<marquee>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[/move]", "</marquee>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[img]", "<img border = \"0\" src = ", $text);
$text = str_replace("[/img]", ">", $text);
$text = str_replace("[code]", "<div id=code>", $text);
$text = str_replace("[/code]", "</div>", $text);
$text = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n", "\r"), '<br />', $text); 

//Racial Hatred Blocking
include("snippets/racial_violations.php");

return $text;
}
```

The question i wanted to ask is how would I go about checking if $text contained say:

- "foo"
- "yar"
- "bar"

By passing my text var to the function (in a similar to the way i've done it above), but not replacing anything like str_replace does.
I want to then pass out an error from the function so i could use:

```
if($text_error == 1){ echo "text does not contain foo, yar or bar";}
else ( echo "text CONTAINS foo, yar or bar";}
```

$text_error would either be 0 or 1 and would be assigned this value if text contained one of the three specified words.

Hopefully I've explained this sufficiently!

Comment: "quick and efficient" - i'm scared.

Comment: is there a more efficient way?

Comment: It's always better to go with standard solutions: http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php

Comment: i'm not really sure how to implement that solution though

Comment: If you can't install PECL extensions on your box then try this standalone class: http://nbbc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: thank you fabrik!  I'll be sure to look into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perhaps edit the `replace()` function to add in the beginning a check for any such words.

```
function replace($text) {

    $bannedWords = array('foo', 'yar', 'bar') ;
    foreach ($bannedWords as $bannedWord) {
        if (strpos($text, $bannedWord) !== false) {
            return false ;
        }
    }


    //..rest of str_replaces below here


    return $text
}
```

In this case if one of the words is found the function will return the boolean `false`. You can check for that wherever you are calling `replace()`. If none are found then the text will be returned after replacing any BBcode, as before.

So,

```
$replacedText = replace($text) ;
if ($replacedText === false) {
    //$text includes one of the bad words, act accordingly to inform the user
}
else {
    //$text was ok, and has its bbcode replaced, use it accordingly
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I wanted to ask how i would check for say: "foo" and "Foo" without specifying both in the array?   Also, how would i check if the function returned false?

Comment: Seems it should return false if none of the words are in the string. Your function returns false if any of the words is in the string.

Comment: @Callum if you want to check both foo and Foo you should use: `if (strpos(strtolower($text), $bannedWord) !== false)`

Comment: @Callum Use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php or make `$textI = strtolower($text)` and then compare using that. I'm going to edit my answer to show you the false check

Comment: @captaintokyo `(strpos($text, $bannedWord) !== false)` is true if `$bannedWord` has a position in `$text`, ie it exists in it. It's a bit counterintuitive but fast. It gives bool `FALSE` if it was not found.

Comment: @Fanis, yeah, so if any of the words are in `$text` then the function `replace` returns `false`. I was wondering if that is what TS wants. It's not clear from his question.

Comment: This seems to indicate that an error occurs if the words are not in the text: `if($text_error == 1){ echo "text does not contain foo, yar or bar";}`

Comment: I wanted to display an error if the words are found in the text string.

Answer (score 2):

As for how to implement the above code more efficiently: `str_replace` also accepts arrays as its first two arguments:

```
$replace = array('[b]' => '<strong>', '[i]' => '<i>', ...);
$text = str_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass extra variable to function:

```
function replace($text, &$error) {
```

and set it later

```
$error = "text does not contain foo, yar or bar";
```